# What is the meaning of this fiddler icon?

Tags: icons, fiddler

I got a line in fiddler2 looking like this:

```
ICON # status protocol  host               url
XXX  3 200    HTTP      www.myserver.com  /images/save.png
```

The icon shown is a forbidden icon like this: [image]

Actually i am analizing a loading problem in one of our customers intranets.

Can anyone please tell me what this icon stands for?

Comment: @SLaks, I can't necessarily speak for Thariama, but I was able to get that icon on a 200 OK response.

Comment: it was on a 200 response - so i really wonder

Answer (score 58, accepted):

That icon means that the session was aborted by the client, Fiddler, or the Server ([see the documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledgebase/uiguide)).

In the modern versions of Fiddler, right-click the session and choose `Properties`. In the list of flags, there will be an `X-Aborted-When` flag which shows the state of the session at the time that the abort occurred.

Comment: Thx, very much, i was looking on the fiddler page, but wasn't able to find it. Do you have any idea how i can find out which one (client, Fiddler or Server did abort the session) ?

Comment: If you see the response code of 200, and you haven't configured Fiddler to abort the traffic, then it was the client that caused the abort. This would happen if, for instance, the user navigated the browser to a different page before the graphic had been downloaded fully.

Comment: Does the server records the hit? Sometimes this happens with tracking gifs that are fired when users click something that trigger a page load. Does the click is properly tracked or I am missing click counts?

Comment: @EricLaw How do I set Fiddler to abort as you mentioned? Fiddler seems to be resending my request right after it gets aborted the first time, so I can't reproduce my problem because watching with Fiddler changes the outcome.

Comment: @Wiseguy: You should probably start a new question if you're going to ask something unrelated to the original. **Fiddler** doesn't resend your request-- your client application resends it.

Comment: @EricLaw I considered that to avoid cluttering this thread (and I will remove this), but my question was only in relation to what you meant about configuring Fiddler to abort the traffic.

Answer (score 21):

**The meaning of all fiddler's icons of each session**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Fiddler changed their documentation link.

Here is the new link for all the icons:

http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledgebase/uiguide