# Unable to render excel download from aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, http-headers

I have an ASP.NET (webforms) page that renders MS-Excel back to the response stream on click of a button. Everything works perfectly in testing but on live deployment, I get this dialogue box after the browser appears to be trying to download the file:
[image]
where ReportsShow.aspx is the name of the aspx page that generates and renders the excel.
The button that triggers the download fires a postback so I am confounded as to why the page would not be found when it renders correctly on load?
I am clueless and any help would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT**: As requested by Mayank, here's the code structure:

```
        // Get instance of reporting service
        IReportingService reportingServiceClient = Reports.GetWebService();
        // Get a fresh copy of the report
        BusinessReport theReport = reportingServiceClient.GetReport(AcctList.ToArray());

        ExcelExport excelExport = new ExcelExport();

        const string templateFileName = "Business-Report.xls";
        string newFileName = String.Empty;

        try
        {
            newFileName = excelExport.CopyTemplateFile(Server.MapPath("~/ExportTemplates/" + templateFileName));
            excelExport.WriteData(forexOptionReport, newFileName);

            Response.Clear();

            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("Attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", "Business-Report" + ".xls"));
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

            Response.TransmitFile(newFileName);
            Response.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Errors.LogException("Error in Reports.BtnDownloadToExcel_Click", ex);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(newFileName))
            {
                excelExport.DeleteFile(newFileName);
            }
        }
```

**MORE INFO**

I've analyzed this with fiddler and this is what I see for the particular request/response which is expected to present the excel for download:

[image]

[This Stackoverflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874436/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-fiddler-icon) states that the meaning of the forbidden icon is that the client is terminating/aborting the response

Comment: can you share your code...so that we can look what you have done to do this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this issue. The details are as described in [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/03/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx.)

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234044/asp-net-mvc-and-ie-caching-manipulating-response-headers-ineffective) has some details and resources that would clarify what was happening.
The basic issue is that IE versions 8 and below fail to download files over SSL when they see the following headers in the response:
Cache-control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache

These headers should be removed and replaced with:

```
Response.Headers.Set("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=0");
```