# What does the red circle cross in the '#' column means?

Tags: fiddler

What does the red circle cross in the '#' column means?
[image: Screenshot]

I come across this while while I was debugging an issue that only repros on IE.  (FYI the issue is that the JSON in the response fails to bind to my knockout model on IE... but it is working fine on Chrome...).  I have tried replaying that request (Replay > Reissue Requests) and I am seeing that the second request returns a '{json}' icon.

I am trying to understand what fiddler is telling me with the first request.  What does that red circle cross means?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A red circle with a line through it in the Web Sessions list means the session was aborted by the client, Fiddler, or the server.

The associated icon makes it look like an error, but it isn't always. The result was "200 OK", the standard HTTP response for a successful request. Fiddler is most likely telling you that IE closed the connection before it received a response from Fiddler, so it's setting the state of the request to "aborted."

Edit: The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874436/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-fiddler-icon) from Eric Law mentions configuring Fiddler to abort traffic to prevent this from occuring with a 200 response code.